# Using a generic interface as a return type in java

Tags: java, generics, interface

Hello I have the following interface and two objects imepleting it in the following way

```
public interface MyObject<T> {
  T getId();
  String getName();
}

public class ObjectA implements MyObject<Integer> {
  @Override
  public Integer getId() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "A";
  }
}

public class ObjectB implements MyObject<Long> {
  @Override
  public Long getId() {
  return 0;
 }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "B";
  }
```

}

I want to create another interface that declares a method returning an object of type MyObject

```
public interface AnotherObject {
  public MyObject<?> getmyObject();
}
```

Is this the correct way to use a generic type object as the return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've written the interface `AnotherObject`, it will compile.  But the wildcard means that any type parameter can be returned.  Getting the `MyObject` object and calling `getId` on it must return an `Object`, which isn't very useful.

You can define the type parameter `T` on the interface, and it will be in scope on the return type of `getMyObject`, where you can refer to it.

```
public interface AnotherObject<T> {
    public MyObject<T> getMyObject();
}
```

This way, the `MyObject` can return a type of `T`.  In practice, you may have `AnotherObject<Integer>` that can return a `MyObject<Integer>` whose `getId()` method returns an `Integer` instead of an `Object`.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused about adding unnecessary generic types.